# Persist cell value in excel

Tags: excel

This is my current excel document

```
Balance      Deposit       Withdrawal
$45.00       $100.00       $50.00
             $25.00        $30.00
```

The function for cell `A1` is `==SUM(B2:B) - SUM(C2:C)`. However, when I delete the values from columns B and C, the value of balance goes back to 0. I want the value to stay at $45.

I have tried many forms and here is one of my thoughts: `=A2 + SUM(B2:B) - SUM(C2:C)`. But this doest work either...

Comment: Your logic is counter-intuitive. If *Balance = Deposits - Withdrawals* then why should you delete the data by which you calculated the correct result? Consider either hiding the rows that no longer interest you on a daily basis, or move the entire calculation to another sheet and let columns B and C just show the last 5 entries from whatever list there is. The point is that A1 should always show the difference between deposits and withdrawals, not some number which nobody can check the correctnesss of.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the cell has a formula, it will count even if there are no numbers in columns B and C. To get rid of a formula, select a cell (A1 in this case), then `Copy`, then `Paste special` -> `Values`. Then you can delete the values in columns B and C.

Comment: Well I dont really want to get rid of the formula. If I delete the values in B and C, I want A1 to stay at $45. Then if I later add $50 to deposit, then the balance would change to $95

Comment: With formula you will not be able to do that, you should try VBA